# Toggle click function

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, so i successfully toggled a bool and some other options.

But whenever i make another click function for another button to toggle the bool to false, it doesn't work.

My code:

```
    let managementbool = false;
    $("#management").on('click', function(){
        managementbool = true;

        if(managementbool)
        {
            $(".dot1").hide();
            $(".dot2").hide();
            $(".topbar").hide();
            $(".boostingtext").hide();
            $(".mainbar").hide();
            $("#container").hide();
    
            $(".dot11").show();
            $(".dot22").show();
            $(".topbar1").show();
            $(".boostingtext1").show();
            $(".mainbar1").show();
        }
    });

    $("#contracts").click(function () {
        managementbool = false;

        $(".dot11").hide();
        $(".dot22").hide();
        $(".topbar1").hide();
        $(".boostingtext1").hide();
        $(".mainbar1").hide();

        $(".dot1").show();
        $(".dot2").show();
        $(".topbar").show();
        $(".boostingtext").show();
        $(".mainbar").show();
        $("#container").hide();
    });
```

First button to toggle it to true works, but whenever i click the button that sets it to false. Nothing happens.

Comment: Share html code too. It's need to advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add your function correctly. `$("#contracts").on('click', function() { ... });` should work.

Also take a look at whether you really need your `managementbool` variable. When I click on `#management` you set it to `true` and thus always execute the code in your if-statement, making the if-statement redundant. In the code segment you show, it seems you never actually do anything based on the value of `managementbool`.

```js
$("#show").on('click', function() {
  $("#some_element").show();
});

$("#hide").on('click', function() {
  $("#some_element").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="show">Show</button>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>

<div id="some_element">Test</div>
```

Comment: Yes i agree. But even if i remove the if statement and bool. And i use my contracts click function it wont execute to hide visible ones then show the ones i hid with the management click function

Comment: Did you update this part? `$("#contracts").on('click', function() { ... });`

Comment: I've added a working code example. Please check if you didn't make a typo when naming the class or id of the elements.

Comment: Note that this format  `$("#contracts").click(function () {})` is also correct format